# Does 'constant' mean independent of the main variables?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, notation, terminology

What is the meaning of 'constant' when given as an unspecified term in an expression?

I'm aware of the idea of a 'parameter' we give a term that defines a function or a set of functions, so given $f(x)=ux$, we can consider it giving us a new function $f$ for each $u$, if $f$ retains it's identity, the number multiplied by $x$ must also do so.

However, in many cases we are told things like the following:

'If $a,b,c$ are constants then $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is a quadratic equation in $x$'

What makes them 'constant' here? They can be independent, is it that for a given $a,b,c$ we get a particular equation to be solved? Does it simply mean 'independent' of all other variables (or at least independent of the arguments and unknowns), because of course if $a=f(x)$ and we get a different equation in $x$ and with any parameter it must be independent of the 'arguments'.

For example if I state that the set of values defined at $y_0$ is given by the equation $f(x)=y_0$ where $y_0$ is a constant, is it a correct understanding that $y_0$ may change from point to point, but must be independent of $x$.

Comment: There is no meaningful distinction between an arbitrary constant and a variable.

Comment: The assertion "$a^2+b^2+c=0$ is a quadratic equation and $a$, $b$,$c$ are constants" sounds odd. By contrast, the superficially-similar "if $a$, $b$, and $c$ are constants, then $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is a quadratic equation in $x$" has a standard, well-understood meaning.

Comment: If $a, b, c$ are real numbers, then $a x^2 + b x + c$ is a quadratic polynomial in $x$. It is not an equation because there is no equal sign. An equation is a constraint.

Comment: In the context of the ring $R[x]$ of polynomials in a variable $x$ over a ring $R$, the constants are the elements of $R$. If there are other cases where you have problems with this notion, then please write a a more specific question.

Comment: @Gribouillis I re-wrote the question and forgot to include '$=0$.

Comment: The author is using the "general form" of the equation: here $x$ denotes the argument place to be filled with input values to compute the output. $a,b,c$ are *constant* because they are not changed by the chosen input value. Of course, if we want to compute the output value we have to consider a specific function, that means we have to instantiate the constant with real values.

Comment: A **constant** whose value is unspecified, a **parameter** and an **arbitrary constant** all mean the same, and has a fixed, unspecified value (unless instantiated) per context/problem. The first term emphasises its fixed value (in contrast with a variable), the second term emphasises its varying value across contexts (in similarity with a variable), while the third term emphasises that its choice of value isn't important. $\quad$ In the context of a constraint problem, a variable is also called an unknown.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm aware of the idea of a 'parameter' we give a term that defines a function or a set of functions, so given f(x)=ux, we can consider it giving us a new function f for each u, if f retains it's identity, the number multiplied by x must also do so.

In your example of "$f(x)=u\cdot x$" you call $u$ a 'parameter'.  Furthermore, you seem to understand that this $u$ parameter has a single fixed value in the context of an individual problem (even though this one symbolic representation could apply abstractly to a great many individual functions).

Relative to the above understanding of a 'parameter', you should just understand 'constant' to be a shorthand phrasing for 'constant parameter' because it is a parameter that maintains a single constant value.

Comment: So, in my more 'general' context if I consider different $u$, then the only thing that differentiates 'u' from any other variable is that it cannot depend on any variable used to denote argument.

Comment: @user37577 Yes.  If your parameter has a relationship that *changes* depending on the values of the input arguments then it can no longer be a 'constant parameter' by definition (owing to the definitions of 'changing' and 'constant' being incompatible simultaneously).